# Showing a subset in $\mathbb R^2$ is connected.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let the subset be ${(x, y) : (x + 1)^2 + y^
2 < 1  \lor (x − 1)^2 + y
^2 ≤ 1}$. Conclude whether this subset is connected, and justify your decision.

Having drawn a diagram, it is clear to me that this is connected, and I should use path connected implies connected to prove this. I think the idea is to show that from any point in one circle, I can reach the centre of the circle, go from the centre of that circle to the centre of the other circle and then to any point in that circle but I am unsure how to actually do that.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Yeah, that was my idea and it is clear why it is true but I am unsure on how to actually write that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proposed proof is perfectly fine; there's a simpler version, though. The point $(0,0)$ is in both "parts" of the sets, and both parts are convex. (Well...to be fair, I should say that it *would* be in the left part if it were a less-than-or-equal thing.)

Anyhow, to get from $(a,b)$ to $(p, q)$, you can construct the path
$$
\gamma(t) =  \begin{cases} 
(1-2t) (a,b) + 2t(0,0) & t \le \frac12\\
(1 - 2(t-\frac12)) (0,0) + 2(t- \frac12)(p,q) & t \ge \frac12
\end{cases}
$$
which is a straight-line path starting at $(a,b)$ at $t = 0$ and reaching $(0,0)$ at $t = \frac12$, and then another straight line path from $(0,0)$ (at $t = \frac12$) to $(p,q)$ at $t = 1$.

**Post-comment addition**

In general, if $A$ and $B$ are points in Euclidean space, then the path
$$
\alpha(t) = (1-t)A + t B ~~ (0 \le t \le 1)
$$
has $\alpha(0) = (1-0)A + O \cdot B = 1 \cdot A = A$, and $\alpha(1) = B$, similarly. Furthermore, each coordinate is an affine function of $t$, so the plot of this path is a straight-line-segment.

If we double $t$ to write 
$$
\alpha_1(t) = (1-2t)A + 2t B ~~ (0 \le t \le \frac12)
$$
then we have $\alpha_1(t) = \alpha(2t)$ so $\alpha_1$ gives a path starting at $A$ and ending at $B$, but it gets to $B$ at $t = \frac12$ rather than at $t = 1$. That's how I built the first part of the rule for $\gamma$. The second part of the rule uses the same idea...but it needs to operate on the interval $\frac12 \le t \le 1$, so I found a function, namely "subtract $\frac12$ to get to $0 \le t \le \frac12$, and then double" that would re-map this to the interval $0 \le t \le 1$.

Comment: Thanks. How did you come up with the actual equations for the path?

Comment: See post-comment addition.

Comment: Perfect. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the set$$X=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid(x-1)^2+y^2<1\}\cup\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid(x+1)^2+y^2\leqslant1\}$$is connected: for each $p$ in it, the line segment joining $(0,0)$ to $p$ is contained in $X$. Therefore, $X$ is path-connected: you can always go from $P$ to $(0,0)$ and then from $(0,0)$ to any othe point $q$.

Comment: But it's $(x − 1)^2 + y^2 ≤ 1}$ not $(x − 1)^2 + y^2 < 1}$? I also don't understand what you mean by them both being open and closed

Comment: Right. I missed that and I've edited my answer.

Comment: If the question just said "justfy why it is connected", would it be enough to state what you have said, or would I actually need to find the formula of the lines. If so how would I do this?

Comment: The formula is obvious: if you want to go from $(0,0)$ to $P$, you take $t\mapsto tp$, with $t\in[0,1]$.